# Wordpress trigger update/publish button click from functions.php file

Tags: jquery, wordpress, function, eventtrigger

My custom post type section is quite long, so I've broken it up into 7 "steps" with buttons added via jquery that take the user to the next "step" by hiding the first section and revealing the next.

How would I trigger the publish or update button click when clicking on the "next step" button?

I've tried several solutions - none seem to be working.

The "step button" code:

```
jQuery('#button-1').live('click',function(){    
    jQuery('#acf_89').show();
    jQuery('#acf_88').hide();           
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

To trigger a button click event you can call .click()

```
jQuery('#button-1').live('click',function(){    
    jQuery('#acf_89').show();
    jQuery('#acf_88').hide();   
    $("#button_id").click();
 });
```

Comment: I need the click on #button-1 to also call the events for the update/publish button in wordpress. I know jQuery trigger could work, but evidentally I'm not using it correctly in this case.

Comment: Can you show the code where you are trying to trigger the click event on the update/publish button?

Comment: calling .click() with no handler inside is shorthand for .trigger('click'). what flynfish is suggesting is to do just that. trigger a click on the actual update button.

Comment: I am glad it worked for you! Did you know you can mark one answer per question as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with triggering a click on the "Update" button is that you will reload the page and lose your position in your custom walk-through wizard.

To save the post on the fly you will need to augment your Wordpress install with something like [Ajax Post Save](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-save-post/)